# Why is my navigation bar and footer is not stretching to full width?

Tags: html, css

Why is my navigation bar and footer not stretching to the full width?
I tried to remove the container a d 'CLASSNAME' however still nothing happens, I know it is something simple and maybe I am just over looking it.

```css
    body {
       font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       padding:0;
       margin-left:  200px;
    margin-right:  200px;

      background: linear-gradient(90deg, gainsboro 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 10%,
                                                        rgb(255,255,255) 90%, gainsboro 100%);
    
}



.CLASSNAME {
    position:relative
} 
/*Global*/
.container{
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 16px;
}



/*Header*/
header{
    background: #19252A;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding-top:5px;
    min-height:70px;
    
  
}

header a{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px;
    
}




header li{
    /*float:left;*/
    display:inline;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px; 
}

.logo{
    padding-left: 75px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-top: 2px;
}

nav{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    
}

header nav{
    float:right;
    margin-top:10px;

}

header .highlight, header .current a{
    color:#e8491d;
    font-weight:bold;
    
}

header a:hover{
    color:#cccccc;
    font-weight:bold;
}


/*Slideshow*/

.slideshow{
    height: 425px;
    width: 100%;
}



.slide_img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 426px;
}

.slide_img img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#i1, #i2, #i3, #i4{
    display: none;
} 

.pre, .nxt {
    width: 12%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(88,88,88,-4); 
    z-index: 99;
    cursor: pointer; 
}

.pre{
    left: 0; 
}

.nxt{
    right: 0;
} 

.nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 12%;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 370px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 99;
    
}


.dots{
    top: -5px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin: 0 4px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

.slide_img{
    z-index: -1;
}

#i1:checked ~ #one,
#i2:checked ~ #two,
#i3:checked ~ #three,
#i4:checked ~ #four{
    z-index: 9;
}

#i1:checked ~ .nav #dot1,
#i2:checked ~ .nav #dot2,
#i3:checked ~ .nav #dot3,
#i4:checked ~ .nav #dot4{
    background: #fff;
}

/*Footer*/

footer {
       text-transform: uppercase;

   
    background: #19252A;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;
    border-top: 15px solid #fff;
    font-size: 7.5px;
}


 .box2 p {
      position:relative;
        float:left;
        
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="CLASSNAME">
           <div>
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img class="logo" src="img/stars-logo.png" alt="" />
                    </a>
                

                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Workshops</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Classes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Our Teachers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Our Kids</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Out Of School</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Twinkle Parties</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                </div>
             

            </div>
        </div>
        </header>
    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="CLASSNAME">
                <input type="radio" name="images" id="i1" checked>
                <input type="radio" name="images" id="i2">
                <input type="radio" name="images" id="i3">
                <input type="radio" name="images" id="i4">
                       
                <div class="slide_img" id="one">
                <img src="img/STARS%2027.jpg">
                    <label for="i4" class="pre"></label>
                    <label for="i2" class="nxt"></label>

                </div>
                
                <div class="slide_img" id="two">
                <img src="img/STARS%2020.jpg">
                    <label for="i1" class="pre"></label>
                    <label for="i3" class="nxt"></label>
                </div>                   
             
                <div class="slide_img" id="three">
                <img src="img/STARS%2027.jpg">
                    <label for="i2" class="pre"></label>
                    <label for="i4" class="nxt"></label>
                </div>
            
                <div class="slide_img" id="four">
                <img src="img/STARS%2020.jpg">
                    <label for="i3" class="pre"></label>
                    <label for="i1" class="nxt"></label>
                </div>
                
                <div class="nav">
                <label class="dots" id="dot1" for="i1"></label>
                <label class="dots" id="dot2" for="i2"></label>
                <label class="dots" id="dot3" for="i3"></label>
                <label class="dots" id="dot4" for="i4"></label>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        
        </div>
     <footer>
    
    <div class="container">
    <section class="footer">
        <div class="box2">
        <p>
            
            Phasellus urna eros, facilisis et faucibus sit amet, bibendum quis diam. <br/>Curabitur ornare ultricies pulvinar, facilisis et faucibus sit amet."
            </p>
        
        </div>
    </section>
          </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kayyoung/o72c5u0f/1/ here is a link if someone could help me please

Comment: try removing the margins on the `body`. set the margin to `margin: 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Due to styles applied to body tag, It is behaving like that.

Removed margin-left and margin-right and added margin: 0;

```
 body {
       font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       padding:0;
       margin: 0;

      background: linear-gradient(90deg, gainsboro 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 10%,
                                                        rgb(255,255,255) 90%, gainsboro 100%);

}
```

Comment: Im trying to have a margin on either side or would i need to replace this with a border instead?

Comment: How much margin you want on either side of the navigation bar and footer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of this:

```
body { 
margin-left:  200px; 
margin-right:  200px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO Bradley.

You need to add a width and remove the margins.

You can fix the issue by making the following changes to your body CSS:

```
body {
   font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   padding:0;
   width: 100%;    /* this is added */
   /* margin-left:  200px;   this is removed */
   /* margin-right:  200px;  this is also removed */

  background: linear-gradient(90deg, gainsboro 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 10%,
                                                    rgb(255,255,255) 90%, gainsboro 100%); 
}
```